# How to find only epoch time present column from the dataframe using python pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, pandas

I have a dataframe

```
data = [['true', 'false',-1496188800000], ['false','true', 829008000000], ['true', 'false',],['true','true',1028678400000]]


df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['isconnect', 'isactive','datetime'])
```

I want to find which column is epoch time and get the entire column to convert human-readable date using python pandas.

Note: DateTime column name sometime will be changed.

I tried this code but not working.

```
                for i in df.column.values:
                    if df.i.str.match(r'^[-+]?!*([0-9]!*){10,}$'):
                        df[i] = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(i / 1000).strftime('%Y-%m-%d') + ' UTC'
```

```
 isconnect isactive      datetime
0      true    false -1.496189e+12
1     false     true  8.290080e+11
2      true    false           NaN
3      true     true  1.028678e+12
```

output look like this:

```
  isconnect isactive    datetime
0      true    false  1922-08-04
1     false     true  1996-04-09
2      true    false        None
3      true     true  2002-08-07
```

thanks, advanced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
for i in columnheader:
    if (df[i].dtype == object) and pd.to_datetime(df[i], unit='ms', errors='coerce').dropna().tolist():
        df[i] = pd.to_datetime(df[i], unit='ms', errors='coerce')
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236529/discussion-between-dev-and-u12-forward).

Answer (score 0):

The fact is that in your example, there is no valid date in the datetime column. I changed your example by adding a real unix-timestamp. Now it works:

```py
# 1630226430 - real Unix Timestasmp
data = [['true', 'false',-1496188800000], ['false','true', 1630226430], ['true', 'false',],['true','true',1028678400000]]


df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['isconnect', 'isactive','datetime'])
for col in df.columns:
    df[col] = pd.to_datetime(df[col], unit='s', errors='ignore')

df
    isconnect   isactive    datetime
0   true    false   -1496188800000.0
1   false   true    2021-08-29 08:40:30
2   true    false   NaT
3   true    true    1028678400000.0
```